# get URL Parameter from Laravel blade to controller

Tags: laravel, url, parameter-passing

I already have provided my blade with a link that passes a parameter.

```
<a href="{!! route('search',['id'=>2]) !!}">{{$value}}</a>
```

The only problem I have now is how to get the parameter to the controller.
I do it like this

```
public function search(Request $request){
     $sid = $request->get('id');
}
```

But I'm not getting any value from $sid. How should I do it?

sorry I forgot to mention that there is already a route set.

```
Route::post('search', 'Search@search')->name('search');
```

Comment: i think you need to get like this public function search(Request $request,$id){
     $sid = $id;
}

Comment: your route is post method but your trying to get  a values as a  get method . take a look on my answer

Answer (score 0):

because link are not post method .. this would work

```
<a href="{!! route('search',['id'=>2]) !!}">{{$value}}</a>
```

then in your route

```
Route::get('search/{id}',BlahblahController@search);
```

in your controller

```
public function search(Request $request, $id)
{
    $id = $id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your routes `/youroute/{id}` this scheme then you need to pass one more param to your method in Controller like this

```
public function search(Request $request,$id){
 $sid = $id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your trying to pass url bind `parameter` to function . Not passing `query` string `get` parameter . so you need to access the `id` like this

**Method 1 :**

**Controller :**

```
public function search(Request $request,$id){ $sid = $id; }
```

Your route should be like this

**Route :**

```
Route::get('search/{id}',BlahblahController@search);
```

**Method 2 :**

Or if don't want to bind parameter to url and want just $_GET parameter like `url/?id=1`

You may use it like this

**Controller :**

```
public function search(Request $request){
     $sid = $request->get('id');
}
```

**Route :**

```
 Route::get('search',BlahblahController@search);
```

Comment: method 2 is my current code.. but I'm confused why $sid on controller still have no value

Comment: No you used post method in route Route::post('search', 'Search@search')->name('search'); change this get method like this  Route::get('search', 'Search@search')->name('search');